# C++ LoadLibrary() from the current path

Tags: c++, dll

I'm a .net developer mostly, doing something small in C++ so im having a little trouble.

I'm loading another C++ dll using `hInst = LoadLibrary(TEXT("mydll.dll"));` and I came to realize that this looks for the dll I'm trying to load in 'C:\' or in 'system32'.

Can someone show me how to load the dll from the current directory (without knowing what the current directory is ahead of time) ??

I know I should be using something like `GetFullPathName` but I'm having a little trouble getting it to work on my own...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The process current directory can be acquired using the function `GetCurrentDirectory()`:

```
TCHAR bufCurrentDirectory[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
DWORD dwNumCharacters = ::GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, bufCurrentDirectory);
if(dwNumCharacters == 0) error();
```

Now the path to the process's current directory is in `bufCurrentDirectory`, unless the function failed. Just append `"\\mydll.dll"` onto the path, and you have an absolute path to the DLL.

Since the current directory of a process is somewhat variable, it may be better to use the path of the executable. To get the path of the current executable, you can do:

```
TCHAR bufExePath[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };
DWORD dwNumCharacters = ::GetModuleFileName(NULL, bufExePath, MAX_PATH);
if(dwNumCharacters == 0) error();
```

Now `bufExePath` contains the entire path to the exe, including `"\\my.exe"`. Replace `my.exe` with `mydll.dll`, and you'll have the absolute path to the DLL. I would recommend this method over the `GetCurrentDirectory()` method due to security concerns.

Answer (score 4):

I believe loading from current directory is the default and first search. See the MSDN reference

> The first directory searched is the
>   directory containing the image file
>   used to create the calling process
>   (for more information, see the
>   CreateProcess function). Doing this
>   allows private dynamic-link library
>   (DLL) files associated with a process
>   to be found without adding the
>   process's installed directory to the
>   PATH environment variable

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I don't know why but in practice this isn't what happens at all. I posted the line of code in which i use LoadLibrary. When the dll file I'm loading isn't in 'C:\' then it doesn't work. When I copy the dll file to C:\ it works perfect!

Answer (score 2):

Use [GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364934%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Comment: I read about the various different methods to retrieve the directory path, but I'm not a C++ programmer having trouble with it, so i was looking for an example to help me a little more than msdn.